# how to install the android studio ? iam getting error like this

Tags: android, android-studio

when iam installing the android studio  i am getting error like this

```
java.lang.runtimeexception:com.intellij.ide.plugins.pluginmanager$startupAbortedException:org.picocontainer.defaults.DuplicatesComponentKeyRegistrationException: key com.siyeh.ig.inspectionGadgetsPlugin Duplicated
```

Comment: Have you looked in the plugins folder if there **is** a duplicate plugin?

Answer (score 0):

You can encounter this error sometimes when updating from Android Studio 0.1.x to 0.2.x.
If you've encountered the error in this way, they describe the problem and solution here:
http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html

In short, I might try a fresh install.

Answer (score 0):

**Delete** all this folders (**except 'sdk'**) in your installation folder of Android Studio:

```
bin
build.txt
config
Install-Linux-tar.txt
lib
license
LICENSE.txt
NOTICE.txt
plugins
```

Now unzip the new version of Android Studio on this clean :-) place.